# Why does the solution to one system imply the other system has a negative solution?

Tags: convex-optimization

> Consider two systems **A** and **B**:
>
> **A**$: f_i(x) \lt 0, i=1, \dots, m, Ax = b$
>
> **B**$: \min_{\{x,s\}} s$ subject to $f_i(x) - s \le 0, i = 1, \dots, m; Ax = b$
>
> Then **B** has optimal value $p^* \lt 0$ iff there exists a solution to **A**

I can prove $\Rightarrow$ but I'm having trouble showing $\Leftarrow$.

My original attempt was to assume $x$ is the solution of **A**, and therefore: IF $x$ is used in **B** then the smallest $s$ that satisfies the equation must be in $[f_i(x), 0)$ since $f_i(x) \lt 0$.  But this is assuming that for $B$ the same value of $x$ is used.  Which doesn't seem right because $x$ might not work for **B**.

Any ideas?

Comment: can you show the first few steps for $\Leftarrow$?

Comment: A bit of pedantry here: if $B$ is unbounded below—and it certainly can be for certain instances of this—is it correct to say that $B$ has an optimal value $p^*<0$? After all, it has no _finite_ optimal value. @LinAlg what do you think?

Comment: And even if $p^*$ is finite, that doesn't mean there's an $x$ that attains it. (Though there must be such an $x$ for at least one $p$ satisfying $p^*\leq p<0$.)

Comment: You really should combine your two questions together (the other being https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3116263/how-are-these-two-systems-strong-alternatives).

Comment: @MichaelGrant not pedantic: you are right!

Comment: So I'm just not sure the claim is correct as stated, _unless_ we are willing to assume the convention that $p^*=-\infty$ is a legitimate optimal value.

Comment: @MichaelGrant I would assume that $- \infty$ is a legitimate optimal value.  The book explicitly says "The optimal value $p^*$ of this problem (**B**) is negative if and only if there exists a solution to the strict inequality system (**A**)".

Comment: @LinAlg I have added what I tried to the question.

Comment: @OliverG for me the $\Leftarrow$ would start with "assume that there is an $s < 0$ and an $x$ that satisfy $f_i(x) - s \leq 0$, $i=1,\ldots,m$ and $Ax=b$". You can then argue from there.